# How properly unmount state within ComponentWillUnmount to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I pass a component state as a prop to another component. It is really large. Do I have to reset the state while parent component unmounted? I just want to avoid memory leaks.

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch({ /* ... */ })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        result: responseData.meta.data
      })
    })
}
  
componentWillUnmount(){
  this.setState({
    result: undefined // IS THAT RIGHT APPROACH?
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <DataComponent data={this.state.result}>

    </DataComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: you dont need to!! react will handle state cleanup stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent memory leaks, you don't have to perform this state change in *componentWillUnmount* method. Unmounting the component would remove the state, and so would the reference to the responseData.meta.data, which you stated is large.

There is also another downside to this solution. This type of optimization lowers your code readability and may complicate the maintenance process in future. So try not to use this in your code as it is considered against the clean code principle.

Comment: I just want to make sure there is no references left to the state object even from child component I pass the state as a prop

Comment: @JohnGlabb When a component unmounts, the entire sub-ReactTree it renders is also unmounted.

Answer (score 1):

If your component uses custom `element.addEventListener()`s, then you will want to use `removeEventListener()` in your `componentWillUnmount()` function. Otherwise, all the clean up for state, `onClick`, and other React-specific functionality is done automatically.

A use case where I've needed to clean up event listeners is when I was using a custom vanilla-JS library that didn't have a React equivalent and I had to manually set up and later remove listeners. If I didn't and I recreated the JS component, then events would be handled twice (or more depending on how many times the component was recreated) causing weird things to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to reset the state while parent component unmounted?

You don't need to cull the local component state, React/Javascript handles garbage collecting it when it is no longer referenced.

There's also no point an enqueueing a state update in `componentWillUnmount` since the component is unmounting and there will be no further render cycle.

Note also from the [`componentWillUnmount`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) docs:

> ## componentWillUnmount()
>
> ```
> componentWillUnmount()
> ```
>
> `componentWillUnmount()` is invoked immediately before a component is
> unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method,
> such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning
> up any subscriptions that were created in `componentDidMount()`.
>
> You **should not call setState()** in `componentWillUnmount()` because
> the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is
> unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

Use this lifecycle method to clean up non-state-related code, like event listeners, timers, subscriptions, cancel in-flight network requests, etc.

```
controller = null;

componentDidMount() {
  this.controller = new AbortController();
  const { signal } = this.controller;

  fetch({ /* ... */ }, { signal })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        result: responseData.meta.data
      });
    });
}
  
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.controller?.abort();
}
```